# Defining the bounds for a regex negative look behind with ICU

Tags: c++, regex, icu

I have patterns like the following

```
header line
  a = b
  c = d
  c = e
  f = g
```

I've come up with the pattern

```
std::string pat = 
"((.*)(\n|\r\n)(\\s|\\t)*?(?<name>([a-z]{1,100}))\\s+=)"
"((.*)(\n|\r\n)(\\s|\\t)*?(?<!\\k<name>{1,100})\\s+=)";
```

Using [ICU's regex](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) I get `U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT`.
I thought the `{1,100}` is what I needed but that has no effect. How do I get the look behind to take the limit I'm giving?

Or is there a simpler way to do this? If it's not clear, I want a pattern that matches whenever the first word of a line is different to the first word of the previous line, so it would match when it encounters `c = d` and again when it encounters `f =` but wouldn't for `c = e`.

Comment: ICU regex does not support non-fixed-width look-behind.

Comment: You might consider trying `std::regex` in C++11.

Comment: @stribizhev I found that out just before posting that's why I changed the <name> capture group from `[a-z]+` to `[a-z]{1,100}` thinking that'd make it fixed-width.

@JohnZwinck - I can't switch to `std::regex` at the moment, it'd take a great deal of time to do the switch. From first glance though at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex , it doesn't look like C++11 regex has unicode support which is a requirement

Comment: Split by newline, check if the first word is the same as the word from the previous line. Only .NET regex (or Python regex module) and Java can handle look-behinds of variable width.

Comment: @stribizhev: ICU supports bounded variable-length lookbehinds like Java does, so `(?<![a-z]{1,100})` would be legal.  The problem is the backreference.   It doesn't matter how complex the referenced group is, backreferences are not allowed in lookbehinds.

Comment: @AlanMoore any suggestions on achieving the comparison without the back reference?

Comment: So, that is what *The length of possible strings matched by the look-behind pattern must not be unbounded (no \* or + operators.)* mean... Still, there is no way to do that with regex, I also noticed the back-reference in look-behind issue later when trying my hand at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^\h*(?<name>\w++)\h*=.*\R(?=\h*(?<good>(?!\k<name>\b)\w++\h*=.*$))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pK8iW5/1)

I've basically turned your solution on its head.  I match the *previous* line in the normal way, then matches the *current* line in a lookahead.  The lookahead lets me look at the whole line without advancing the current match position.  This is why the next match attempt starts on the next line, not the one after it.

Although the lookahead doesn't *consume* what it matches, you can still *capture* parts of the matched text in groups.  Here I've captured the current line in group named `good`.

A word about some of my other changes: `\R` is the platform-neutral newline construct, which is much more robust than `(\n|\r\n)`. `\h` matches horizontal whitespace characters like spaces and TABs, but not vertical whitespace, like linefeeds and carriage returns.  Note that `\h` is not the same as `(\s|\t)`.  Many new users assume `\s` only matches the space character, but it actually matches *any* whitespace characters, horizontal or vertical.

Here's the regex as a C string literal:

```
"(?m)^\\h*(?<name>\\w++)\\h*=.*\\R(?=(?<good>\\h*(?!\\k<name>\\b)\\w++\\h*=.*$))"
```

Note that it doesn't work on the first line, but I'm assuming it doesn't need to.